# Can C++ struct static member variables shadow non type template parameters?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, non-type-template-parameter

msvc compiles the following code(with /permissive- compiler switch), clang and gcc [do not](https://godbolt.org/z/Gn1Whn8T8):

```
template<auto val>
struct S{
    static constexpr auto val = val;
};
int main() {
    return S<4>::val;
}
```

I presume that this is just a msvc bug, but I am curious if maybe standard is ambiguous here.

Comment: My understanding (having come across this when getting MSVC code compiling with GCC) is that MSVC has this down as an extension.

Comment: You should mention in your question that MSVC compiles this successfully with `/permissive-` (according to your godbolt link). It's an important detail.

Comment: Suggestion to [report the bug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/how-to-report-a-problem-with-the-visual-cpp-toolset?view=msvc-160)

Comment: @Frank fixed, ty

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard is unambiguous on this, a template parameter can't be redeclared for any reason, see [[temp.local]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp#local-6):

> A template-parameter shall not be redeclared within its scope (including nested scopes). A template-parameter shall not have the same name as the template name.
>
> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class T, int i> class Y {
>   int T;            // error: template-parameter redeclared
>   void f() {
>     char T;         // error: template-parameter redeclared
>   }
> };
>
> template<class X> class X;      // error: template-parameter redeclared
> ```
>
> *— end example* ]

So MSVC behavior (given the `/permissive-` flag) looks like a bug.

Comment: If I had a guess... MSVC is treating `T` as a typename and thus not failing because of the name separation between types and declarations... but the example in the standard is unequivocal that is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

[[temp.local]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.local#6):

> The name of a *template-parameter* shall not be bound to any following
> declaration contained by the scope to which the template-parameter
> belongs.
>
> [*Example 5:*
>
> ```
> template<class T, int i> class Y {
>   int T;                                // error: template-parameter hidden
>   void f() {
>     char T;                             // error: template-parameter hidden
>   }
>   friend void T();                      // OK: no name bound
> };
>
> template<class X> class X;              // error: hidden by template-parameter
> ```
>
> — *end example*]

A declaration of a static data member plainly binds a name, so it is just as ill-formed.